# MUI Autocomplete - options text is not visible

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

The text of auto-complete options are not visible, although functionally they exist, because after clicking on a flag - the text is displayed and visible (Photo attached)

How can this be resolved?

I'll note that I'm manipulating the "countries" array options as you can see in the code I've attached:

```
// countriesData.ts
function countryData(local: string): CountryDataType[] {
  const countryData: CountryDataType[] = []
  for (const countryObj of countryDataBase) {
    const newObj: CountryDataType = { ...countryObj } // Create a shallow copy of the original object
    const matchinglabel = countriesLabels[local].find(
      (labelObj) => labelObj.code === newObj.code
    ) // Find the matching label object based on the code
    if (matchinglabel && matchinglabel.label) {
      newObj.label = matchinglabel.label // Add a new field with key "label" and value of the label in the local language
    }
    countryData.push(newObj) // Push the modified object to the new array
  }
  return countryData
}

export default countryData
```

.

```
// Subscribe.ts
import countriesData, { CountryDataType } from '@/utils/countriesData'

  useEffect(() => {
    if (locale !== undefined) {
      setCountries(countriesData(locale))
    }
  }, [locale])
```

.

```
      <Autocomplete
        className={styles.autocomplete}
        id="country-select"
     
        sx={{
          '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
            borderRadius: '100vw',
          },
        }}
        options={countries}
        autoHighlight
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label ?? ''}
        renderOption={(props, option) => (
          <Box component="li" {...props}>
            <Image
              loading="lazy"
              width={20}
              height={15}
              src={`https://flagcdn.com/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.svg`}
              quality={100}
              alt={option.label ?? ''}
            />
          </Box>
        )}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            className={styles.autocompleteInput}
            {...params}
            label={countryLabelText}
            placeholder={countryPlaceholder}
            value={countryValue}
            name="country"
            inputProps={{
              ...params.inputProps,
              autoComplete: 'off', // Disable autocomplete and autofill
              'aria-autocomplete': 'none', // Assistive technology attribute for autocomplete
            }}
            required
          />
        )}
        onChange={handleCountryChange}
        onBlur={handleCountryBlur}
      />
      {countryError && (
        <Typography
          variant="caption"
          color="error"
          className={styles.inputError}
        >
          {countryError}
        </Typography>
      )}
```

[image]

Comment: The text isn’t visible because you aren’t rendering it in your `renderOption` function.